# Which software supports DoD 5220-22-M 7 pass standard for SLES 10.4?

Tags: security, sles

"DoD 5220-22-M 7 pass standard" is a secure deletion method. But what software supports it for a SLES 10.4 64bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to wipe out your driver, [dban](http://www.dban.org/) could do it. It supports `DoD 5220.22-M`, but just for entire drivers. It is a bootable iso.

To delete files, [scrub](https://github.com/chaos/scrub) is the way, and it supports `DoD 5220.22-M`, `Peter Gutmann's 35 pass`, `Roy Pfitzner's 33-random-pass/7-random-pass` and others.

Pre-compiled scrub SLED package [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/10557939/dir/opensuse/com/diskscrub-1.9-3.1.x86_64.rpm.html).

**Related Stuff:**

[What constitutes a Scrub “Pass”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368647/34720)